# How to use only the latest state of a particular record in Materialized view?

Tags: clickhouse

Let's say I have a table defined as

```
CREATE TABLE orders (
    sqlId Int64, -- orders.id from PSQL
    isApproved UInt8, -- Boolean
    comment String,
    price Decimal(10, 2),
    createdAt DateTime64(9, 'UTC'),
    updatedAt DateTime64(9, 'UTC') DEFAULT NOW()
)
ENGINE = MergeTree
ORDER BY (createdAt, sqlId)
```

so two fields that might be changed in the source PSQL database - `isApproved` and `comment`

Naturally, if I sink some records from an MQ topic into it, I will end up with something like this

```
SELECT *
FROM orders

Query id: 50cd95a4-e581-41b5-82a4-7ec86771e4e5

┌─sqlId─┬─isApproved─┬──price─┬─comment───┬─────────────────────createdAt─┬─────────────────────updatedAt─┐
│     1 │          1 │ 100.00 │ some note │ 2021-11-08 16:24:07.000000000 │ 2021-11-08 16:27:29.000000000 │
└───────┴────────────┴────────┴───────────┴───────────────────────────────┴───────────────────────────────┘
┌─sqlId─┬─isApproved─┬──price─┬─comment─┬─────────────────────createdAt─┬─────────────────────updatedAt─┐
│     1 │          1 │ 100.00 │         │ 2021-11-08 16:24:07.000000000 │ 2021-11-08 16:27:22.000000000 │
└───────┴────────────┴────────┴─────────┴───────────────────────────────┴───────────────────────────────┘
┌─sqlId─┬─isApproved─┬──price─┬─comment─┬─────────────────────createdAt─┬─────────────────────updatedAt─┐
│     1 │          0 │ 100.00 │         │ 2021-11-08 16:24:07.000000000 │ 2021-11-08 16:27:17.000000000 │
└───────┴────────────┴────────┴─────────┴───────────────────────────────┴───────────────────────────────┘
```

In other words, a particular order was created first as a non-approved, then it was approved, then some comment was added.

Let's say I want to create a view that represents the total volume of orders per day.

A naive approach might be:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW orders_volume_per_day (
    day DateTime64(9, 'UTC'),
    volume SimpleAggregateFunction(sum, Decimal(38, 2))
)
ENGINE = AggregatingMergeTree
PARTITION BY toYYYYMM(day)
ORDER BY day
AS SELECT 
    toStartOfDay(createdAt) as day,
    sum(price) as volume
FROM orders
GROUP BY day
ORDER BY day ASC
```

However, it will be using all three redundant records, while I only need to use the latest one.

In my particular example, the view will return 300 (3x100) instead of just 100.

Is there any way to achieve the desired behavior in Clickhouse? I know that I can utilize VersionedCollapsingMergeTree somehow with the sign or version columns, but it seems that tools like clickhouse_sinker or snuba will not support it.

Comment: Mat.View is an insert trigger, it watches inserts.
https://den-crane.github.io/Everything_you_should_know_about_materialized_views_commented.pdf

Comment: You can build ETL which remembers the last value of `price` and sends 0, 0 in the 2 latest inserts.